# PJSIP Registration to IPV4 Server from Nat64 network in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipv6, pjsip

I am developing an IOS app using `pjsip-2.6` and a `IPV4 sip server`. First build pjsip with the following code in `configsite.h`

```
#define PJ_HAS_IPV6 1
```

build got successful. Then i added the libraries into my project.Run the application in `IPV4` network.Its successfully registered and voice call working great.
Then i switched the network to Apple `Nat64` network..Nothings works.Here is my code snippets.

For Creating `udp` transport on `IPV4` i used the following code.

```
    pjsua_transport_config cfg;
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
    cfg.port = 5060;
    // Add UDP transport.
    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, &transport_id);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
```

For Creating transport on IPV6 i used the following code..

```
    pjsua_transport_config cfg;
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
    cfg.port = 5070;
    // Add UDP transport for ipv6
    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP6, &cfg, &transport_id_udp6);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
```

For creating the Account in IPV6 network i added..

```
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str((char*)uname);
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str((char *)passwd);
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("*");
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].scheme=pj_str((char*)"Digest");

    char regUri[PJSIP_MAX_URL_SIZE];
    sprintf(regUri, "sip:%s", sip_server);
    acc_cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(regUri);

    acc_cfg.ipv6_media_use = PJSUA_IPV6_ENABLED;
    acc_cfg.transport_id = transport_id_udp6;
```

It would be better if someone can point me out the problem.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you need to provide some logs. PJSIP provides a lot of information on logs and this can help investigate problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are failed to creating the transport in IPV6 network.

One patch available for this (Link: https://github.com/johanlantz/pj-nat64)
you need to integrate that patch for NAT64 issue below are the steps to follow.

1)  Download the pj-nat64 source from above link.

2) Unzip the file and copy pj-nat64.c file paste into the pjproject (means pjsip source) (path is: pjsip/src/pjsua-lib)

3) Copy pj-nat64.h file paste into the pjproject (means pjsip source) (path is: pjsip/include/pjsua-lib)

4) Need to add the pj-nat64.o in the makefile of pjsip (Make file path is: pjsip/build)

5) Open the makefile and search for the string in doubles quotes “Defines for building PJSUA-LIB library” there add the pj-nat64.o after pjsua_vid.o

6) Compile the pjsip source for all architecture and take the Library files and headers files

7) After Pjsua_start method has returns success. Include the below lines.

#if defined(PJ_HAS_IPV6) && PJ_HAS_IPV6 == 1

pj_nat64_enable_rewrite_module();

#endif

8) Add the below code in on_reg_state2() method for calls.

```
    the_transport = rp->rdata->tp_info.transport;
    NSLog(@"transport called %s",the_transport->factory->type_name);

     if (the_transport->factory->type & PJSIP_TRANSPORT_IPV6) 
     {
        ipv4=FALSE;
        NSLog(@"enter into the ipv6 loop ");
        pjsua_var.acc[0].cfg.ipv6_media_use=PJSUA_IPV6_ENABLED ;
        nat64_options option=NAT64_REWRITE_INCOMING_SDP | NAT64_REWRITE_ROUTE_AND_CONTACT;
        pj_nat64_set_options(option);
    }
```

Comment: the github project u telling me to add isn't it for invite method...transport is creating in ipv6 network..will provided info work for registration?

Comment: Provide the registration sip logs. So that i check what's going wrong

Comment: @AshokNarvaneni Please help me with the step 4.how do I add this in the makefile ?

Comment: Is there any update on latest libraray like 2.8 or 2.7.2?

Comment: Yes i am also using 2.7, please share if any solution available.